# How convert string utf-8?

Tags: ios, utf-8, nsstring

i've an NSString like this:

```
NSString *word = @"119,111,114,100"
```

So, what i want to do is to convert this NSString to word

So the question is, in which way can i convert a string to a word?

Comment: What do you mean by converting it to a word?

Comment: I think OP wants to interpret the comma-separated integers as bytes, then convert that byte array to an UTF-8 `NSString`.

Comment: yes, byte array to string. But I do not know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// I have added some values to your sample input :-)
NSString *word = @"119,111,114,100,32,240,159,145,141";

// Separate components into array:
NSArray *array = [word componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

// Create NSData containing the bytes:
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:[array count]];
uint8_t *bytes = [data mutableBytes];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
    bytes[i] = [array[i] intValue];
}

// Convert to NSString (interpreting the bytes as UTF-8):
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@", str);
```

Output:

```
word
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSString *word = @"119,111,114,100";
NSArray *array=[word componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
for (NSString *string in array) {
   char character=[string integerValue];
    NSLog(@"%c",character);    
}
```

Output:

```
w
o
r
d
```

Answer (score 0):

[libicu](http://site.icu-project.org/) it's an UTF8 library that supports a conversion from an array of bytes as stated [here](http://userguide.icu-project.org/conversion/detection).

The thing is, it offers Java, C or C++ APIs, not obj-c.